# what is wrong with my compress function

Tags: python, operator-keyword

```
def compress(vit,bit): 
    s = ''
    x = iter(vit)
    y = iter(bit)

    z = list(vit)
    try:
        while True:
            v1 = next(x)
            v2 = next(y)

            if z.index(v1) == v2:
                s += str(v1)
    except StopIteration:
        pass
    return s
```

The compress generator takes two iterables as parameters: it produces every value from the first iterable that has its equivalent position in the second iterable representing what Python would consider a True value. for example,

```
for i in compress('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', (is_prime(i) for i in irange(1,26))):
    print(i,end='')
```

it returns 'bcegkmqsw'

when it takes

```
('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',[is_prime(i) for i in irange(1,26)])])
```

it supposed to print `'bcegkmqsw'` but my function prints `'ab'`

can anyone tell me how to fix it?

This is the error I got:

```
 17 *Error: ''.join([str(v) for v in compress('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',[is_prime(i) for i in irange(1,26)])]) -> ab but should -> bcegkmqsw
 18 *Error: ''.join([str(v) for v in compress('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',(is_prime(i) for i in irange(1,26)))]) -> ab but should -> bcegkmqsw
```

Comment: you would be able to figure this out youself if you used meaningfull variable names.

Comment: What is `is_prime`?

Comment: to decide whether it is a prime number

Comment: `irange` should be `xrange`; could you print the result of the two list comprehensions

Comment: @jiahuiding  is the method is_prime(i) defined?

Comment: yes it is defined

Comment: @LittleQ I added the error I got

Comment: What's `is_prime` return?

Comment: it returns all the prime number from range(1,26)

Comment: If that were true then you'd be left with a 2d array, Please try to create an [mcve]

Comment: So the `bit` is list of `2,3,5,7,9,11,13...`, right?

Comment: Yes, it is correct

Comment: I don't think so. You'd better print `[is_prime(i) for i in irange(1,26)]` to do a double-check. If `bit` is list of `2,3,5,7,9,11,13...`, the output should be an empty string "".

Comment: ok, my bad. it actually returns [False, True, True, False, True, False, True, False, False, False, True, False, True, False, False, False, True, False, True, False, False, False, True, False, False, False]

Comment: @LittleQ ok, I got it, thanks a lot :)

Comment: That would mean you need `[i for i in irange(1,26) if is_prime(i)]` although I don't know if that fully resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose

```
s='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
a=[is_prime(x) for x in xrange(1,26)]
```

1. length of `s` is 26; length of `xrange(1,26)` is 25.
   You should correct it by `xrange(1,27)`
2. I think your purpose is gathering charactors at the prime position
   Assume `is_prime(x)` return bool so that `a=[False, True, True, ...]`, you can change your code as follow:

   ```
   try:
       while True:
           v1 = next(x)
           v2 = next(y)

           if v2:
               s += str(v1)
   except StopIteration:
       pass
   ```